# Why does an update from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 delete all configs?

Tags: apache-2.4

When updating apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 (for example with this package https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2) all the configs are deleted. The normally used

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

is now completely deleted, the "new" default file (000-default) has a totally different structure, so it's not even possible to recover by doing copy & paste work.

**Why does this happen and how to prevent this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Report a bug to the team. They shouldn't destroy you configurations. They should ask you what should be done. To be sure, check if there is a backup file named "default.dpkg-old" (or similar, I don't remember exactly the name, I remove them after checking that all is working).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the `sites-available` directory in the way it was intended rather than complaining (understandably though) about the packager overwriting the `default` vhost.

Put the `VirtualHost` declarations in seperate files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and enable them with `a2ensite`. Don't forget to disable `default` with `a2dissite`.